# Featured image: Dynamic image sizes when enlarged with javascript

Tags: post-thumbnails

Is it possible to change the image size served by Wordpress *on the fly*?

I'm experimenting with a 3-column design that allows the visitor to expand the main column to full width. Example here - the 'expand' button appears top right after the page is fully loaded: https://cherryaustin.co.uk/topic/hello-again-world/

Problem is that Wordpress serves the correct featured image 'medium' size (800px width) but, when expanded, the browser enlarges the image so it looks fuzzy. 
[image: Original image: 1400px, served as 800px, stretched to 1251px]

I don't properly understand dynamic images - is there any way to get a larger resize of the thumbnail after the page has been served?

Comment: How as the image been added? With a template tag? Through the visual editor? A widget?

Comment: It's added as a Featured Image in the post editor. The 800px width is my configured thumbnail size. Have you got an idea?